# Schedule Publishing to a Target Source

Tags: publishing

I am trying to Schedule an item to be target published from UAT to a Production environment, is there a solution for this? Because as I understand out of the box, it does not work, I have tried many different options, different agents were implemented. But there was no solution that allowed me to "schedule" to a "target" database. So my scenario is as following, I have UAT(CM) environment, and I want to target publish from it to the my Production(CD), but I also would like to schedule the publishing, I would like to save it and see it right away in UAT, but for the production I would like to schedule for the future day.

Comment: adding a new database+ publishing target?

Comment: Just to clarify, I have a publishing target set up. I need to be able to execute scheduled publishing at a "publishing target".

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach would be to have multiple publishing targets. The standard 'Web' one would be where you publish on your UAT (CM) and your CD would be pointed at a different database (let's call it 'Delivery').

When you are logged into CM, you can choose which publishing targets to push to: 'Web' or 'Delivery'.

You can also configure a publishing agent or use a publishing module for scheduled publishing to push out to the 'Delivery' database.

Some scheduled publishing modules:

- https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Automated_Publisher.aspx
- https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecore_Scheduled_Publish.aspx
- https://mikael.com/2016/03/yet-another-sitecore-scheduled-publishing-engine/

Comment: Publishing agent is set up but once I save it publishes automatically to both the "Delivery" and "Web". Scheduling is my biggest challenge. I need to be able to schedule the publishing to the "Delivery", and execute at a specific date and time.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't specify the target databases for your publishing agent correctly. You probably need to have the publishing agent running at intervals only for 'Web'. Then use a module for a specific timed publish that targets only the 'Delivery'.